# Injecting an element of an Arraylist in Scene Builder

Tags: arraylist, javafx-8, inject, scenebuilder

I have an arraylist thats lentgh is dynamic and that contains a couple of labels, e.g.

**In the controller class I've declared**

```
@FXML private ArrayList<Label> a;
```

**initialization within the controller class...**

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        b.add(new Label("label 1"));
        b.add(new Label("label 2"));
        b.add(new Label("label 3")); //etc...
}
```

Do I have the chance to inject each element of *a* in the Scene Builder via fx:id? a.get(0) instead of a...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the reverse, i.e. declare an ObservableList of `Label` in FXML and inject each of the elements into the controller.

```
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
    <Label fx:id="light" text="Light" />
    <Label fx:id="dark" text="Dark" />
</FXCollections>
```

In the controller :

```
public class YourControllerName implements Initializable {

    ...

    @FXML
    private Label light;

    @FXML
    private Label dark;

    ...
}
```

Comment: good idea! But as I mentioned in my post the length of my arraylist is dynamic. In some cases I've 3 elements and in some cases 25. How can I do it in a dynamical way?

Comment: There is no way to do it in FXML, you may want to go through [Creating dynamic amount of components in FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471827/creating-dynamic-amount-of-components-in-fxml)